# What is the best way to access key/values of a object array when I don't know them?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this array above and I need every property of it

```
let arr = [{'John': 0}, {'Doe': 50}, {'Marry': 100}]
```

How could I extract every single key/value of it, once in theory, I don't know any of them?
I have already tried using object.keys but it returns the indexes of my array.

Comment: You can use `object.keys` for each element in array, no?

Comment: [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You can use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get **keys** from an array of objects.

```js
let arr = [{ John: 0 }, { Doe: 50 }, { Marry: 100 }];

const result = arr.flatMap((o) => Object.keys(o));
console.log(result);
```

**2)** To find all **values** in an array

```js
let arr = [{ John: 0 }, { Doe: 50 }, { Marry: 100 }];

const values = arr.flatMap((o) => Object.values(o));
console.log(values);
```

**3)** If you want to find out all **keys and values** in an object

```js
let arr = [{ John: 0 }, { Doe: 50 }, { Marry: 100 }];

const result = {
  keys: [],
  values: [],
};

for (let obj of arr) {
  Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => {
    result.keys.push(k);
    result.values.push(v);
  });
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```js
const arr = [{'John': 0}, {'Doe': 50}, {'Marry': 100}];


// to iterate over each element in the arry  
arr.forEach(a => {
    // To Iterate over each key in the element object
    Object.keys(a).forEach(k => {
      // to print the value of the 'k' key
      console.log(k + ' : ' + a[k]);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to collect all the keys and values of a nested array of objects, you can use `Array.prototype.reduce` and then collect the keys and values of the nested objects in separate nested arrays, using `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()` respectively:

```js
const arr = [{'John': 0}, {'Doe': 50}, {'Marry': 100}];

const allKeysAndValues = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc.keys.push(...Object.keys(cur));
  acc.values.push(...Object.values(cur));
  return acc;
}, { keys: [], values: [] });

console.log(allKeysAndValues);
```

Answer (score 1):

A one liner could be

```js
 let arr = [{'John': 0}, {'Doe': 50}, {'Marry': 100}]
 
 console.log( arr.map( obj => Object.entries(obj)));
```